# Why do some Synaptic Package Manager actions have to be executed twice on Ubuntu MATE 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate, synaptic

Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Often (maybe always) when Synaptic Package Manager is used to remove packages, it throws a bogus error.  Then I do the exact same action again and it works.

This same action works perfectly in Ubuntu 18.04 (I do not have MATE 18.04 to compare).

For example:

Setting up to remove `xscreensaver` add-ons after `xscreensaver` was previously removed.

[image]

Marked all packages for 'complete removal'

[image]

After I  click 'Apply' it pops up this error box

[image]

After hitting close on the error box

[image]

I change *nothing* but hit 'Apply' again and it works perfectly

[image]

I'm glad it works but would prefer to skip the unnecessary duplication.

What's going on here?

Comment: This may be caused by some circular/cross dependencies between XScreensaver packages. I see this behavior on 16.04 LTS too. So it is not new. I see no issues with simple single packages like `xterm`.

Comment: @N0rbert I am not sure (and cannot confirm at the moment) but I believe it happens on 20.04 when removing old kernels and does not happen on 18.04 when removing old kernels.

Comment: The *broken* section in the left may have clues.

Comment: @N0rbert no packages are listed when I select 'Broken' under 'Custom Filters'. 'Broken' does not appear as a option when I select the 'Status' button.